# Python REGEX remove string containing substring

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script that will scrape a newsletter for URLs. There are some URLs in the newsletter that are irrelevant (e.g. links to articles, mailto links, social links, etc.). I added some logic to remove those links, but for some reason not all of them are being removed. Here is my code:

```
from os import remove
from turtle import clear
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

termSheet = "https://fortune.com/newsletter/termsheet"
html = requests.get(termSheet)
htmlParser = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
termSheetLinks = []

for companyURL in htmlParser.select("table#templateBody p > a"):
    termSheetLinks.append(companyURL.get('href'))

for link in termSheetLinks:
    if "fortune.com" in link in termSheetLinks:
        termSheetLinks.remove(link)
    if "forbes.com" in link in termSheetLinks:
        termSheetLinks.remove(link)
    if "twitter.com" in link in termSheetLinks:
        termSheetLinks.remove(link)

print(termSheetLinks)
```

When I ran it most recently, this was my output, despite trying to remove all links containing "fortune.com":

```
['https://fortune.com/company/blackstone-group?utm_source=email&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_campaign=term-sheet&utm_content=2022080907am', 'https://fortune.com/company/tpg?utm_source=email&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_campaign=term-sheet&utm_content=2022080907am', 'https://casproviders.org/asd-guidelines/', 'https://fortune.com/company/carlyle-group?utm_source=email&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_campaign=term-sheet&utm_content=2022080907am', 'https://ir.carlyle.com/static-files/433abb19-8207-4632-b173-9606698642e5', 'mailto:termsheet@fortune.com', 'https://www.afresh.com/', 'https://www.geopagos.com/', 'https://montana-renewables.com/', 'https://descarteslabs.com/', 'https://www.dealer-pay.com/', 'https://www.sequeldm.com/', 'https://pueblo-mechanical.com/', 'https://dealcloud.com/future-proof-your-firm/', 'https://apartmentdata.com/', 'https://www.irobot.com/', 'https://www.martin-bencher.com/', 'https://cell-matters.com/', 'https://www.lever.co/', 'https://www.sigulerguff.com/']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `  if "fortune.com" in link in termSheetLinks:`
Why are you using the second IN?

Comment: You are actually changing the termSheetLinks list in the for loop, this causes skipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It do not need a `regex` in my opinion - Instead of removing the urls, append only those to a list that do not contain your substrings, eg with a `list comprehension`:

```
[companyURL.get('href') for companyURL in htmlParser.select("table#templateBody p > a") if not any(x in companyURL.get('href') for x in ["fortune.com","forbes.com","twitter.com"])]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

termSheet = "https://fortune.com/newsletter/termsheet"
html = requests.get(termSheet)
htmlParser = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

myList = ["fortune.com","forbes.com","twitter.com"]
[companyURL.get('href') for companyURL in htmlParser.select("table#templateBody p > a") 
     if not any(x in companyURL.get('href') for x in myList)]
```

##### Output

```
['https://casproviders.org/asd-guidelines/',
 'https://ir.carlyle.com/static-files/433abb19-8207-4632-b173-9606698642e5',
 'https://www.afresh.com/',
 'https://www.geopagos.com/',
 'https://montana-renewables.com/',
 'https://descarteslabs.com/',
 'https://www.dealer-pay.com/',
 'https://www.sequeldm.com/',
 'https://pueblo-mechanical.com/',
 'https://dealcloud.com/future-proof-your-firm/',
 'https://apartmentdata.com/',
 'https://www.irobot.com/',
 'https://www.martin-bencher.com/',
 'https://cell-matters.com/',
 'https://www.lever.co/',
 'https://www.sigulerguff.com/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the links after the for iterator will not skip any entry.

```
from os import remove
from turtle import clear
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

termSheet = "https://fortune.com/newsletter/termsheet"
html = requests.get(termSheet)
htmlParser = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
termSheetLinks = []

for companyURL in htmlParser.select("table#templateBody p > a"):
    termSheetLinks.append(companyURL.get('href'))

lRemove = []
for link in termSheetLinks:
    if "fortune.com" in link:
        lRemove.append(link)
    if "forbes.com" in link:
        lRemove.append(link)
    if "twitter.com" in link:
        lRemove.append(link)
for l in lRemove:
    termSheetLinks.remove(l)

print(termSheetLinks)
```